# how to get the parent element id in JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have un ordered list of html elements from the list on clicking any of the list i want to get the parent ul tag id.

```
       <ul id="123">
             <li>
               <li>test1</li>
                 <a href="#" onclick="validate()"/>
                </li>
             </li>
              ........
              ........
         </ul>

function validate(){
         var test=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            alert(test);
          }
```

above validate function test variable result should ul tag id that is 123.

Comment: Also, the `<ul>` is the third parent, not the second parent (and your `<a>` is unclosed)

Comment: Try `$(this).parent('ul').attr('id')`

Comment: looks like you want [`$(this).closest('ul')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: tried the $(this).parent('ul').attr('id') but it coming like undefined

Answer (score 5):

First problem is that your function `validate()` dont know what `this` refers to, so you need to add it like `validate(this)`;

Then we can do it like this.

```
function validate(obj) {
  var test = $(obj).closest("ul").attr('id');
  alert(test);
}
```

Also, you should not really have `<li>` as a child of another `<li>` use something like this structure.

```
<ul id="123">
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="validate(this)">test1</a>
    <ul id="456">
      <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="validate(this)">test2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
function validate(obj) {
  var test = $(obj).closest("ul").attr('id');
  alert(test);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="123">
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="validate(this)">test1</a>

    <ul id="456">
      <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="validate(this)">test2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tried Using validate(this) also it is not working. for information entire UI build at runtime.based on the server side data.i don't want to add another hyper link also over the ul also.any way thanks for the suggestion.